# jquery slide animation with overlapping

Tags: jquery, css, animation, slider

I'm making slider like this [slider with faces](http://www.editoskastingas.lt/en)

i don't know how to make overlaping slide effect like in example (i tried with animation z-index margin but don't works)

Here is my slider which i made http://www.srpskaitedukacija.org/slider/

Comment: It looks like your hiding the previous slide before the new one even starts to slide down. try taking out any call to $.hide()

Comment: Also, if you could put your code on something like jfiddle it'd be a lot easier to work with.